# Let $\varphi: G \to G'$ be an injective homomorphism. If $G'$ is Abelian, then $G$ is Abelian? The context is fundamental groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology, abelian-groups, fundamental-groups

It is known that the image of a homomorphism of an abelian group is abelian ([Here is a proof](https://yutsumura.com/abelian-groups-and-surjective-group-homomorphism/)). I have a related conjecture.

> Let $\varphi: G \to G'$ be an injective homomorphism. If $G'$ is Abelian, then $G$ is Abelian.

Proof: $$\varphi(xy)=\varphi(x)\varphi(y)=\varphi(y)\varphi(x)=\varphi(yx) \implies xy=yx$$

How do we generalize this? If we have

> Let $\varphi: G \to G'$ be a surjective homomorphism. If $G$ has this property, then $G'$ has the same property.

then do we have

> Let $\varphi: G \to G'$ be an injective homomorphism. If $G'$ has this property, then $G$ has the same property.

?

By the way, the context of this is Munkres Topology Lemma 60.5 and Theorem 60.6

[image]

[image]

Comment: Subgroups of abelian groups are abelian.

Comment: So your question is only about the generalization to other properties than abelianness?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Retract implies fundamental subgroup?

Comment: @ArnaudD. Thank you! First question is abelian and second question is generalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a given property $P$ your statements can be rewritten as:

> (1) If $G$ has $P$ then so does a quotient of $G$
>
> (2) If $G'$ has $P$ then so does a subgroup of $G'$

There are lots of examples of $P$ satisfying one of the above, two or none:

- (none) $P$ is "being infinite"
- (only (1)) $P$ is "being finitely genarated"
- (only (2)) $P$ is "being free"
- (both) $P$ is "being abelian"

etc.

There is no general method to check what kind of $P$ you are dealing with. You have to check case-by-case.

Comment: freakish, thank you! Hence, $G'$ a quotient or subgroup of $G$ in those cases? Why?

Comment: @JackBauer If $\varphi:G\to G'$ is surjective then $G'$ is isomorphic to a quotient of $G$ by the first isomorphism theorem. And every quotient can be constructed from a surjective homomorphism. If $\psi:G\to G'$ is injective then $\psi(G)$ is isomorphic to $G$ and $\psi(G)$ is a subgroup of $G'$. And every subgroup can be constructed from an injective homomorphism. Thus we can completely remove the notion of homomorphisms and deal with quotients and subgroups only.